# Using a functor in find_if

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, maps, functor

I was wondering how would I use a template functor as an argument for find_if. I'm not sure about the syntax.

For example, suppose a functor that deletes a product from a multimap of products. To do that, I have to "scan" the multimap, find the product (using my equal functor) and delete it.

Here's my 'equal' functor:

```
class isEqual
{
public:
    isEqual(T* t) : t_(t) {}

    bool operator()(const pair<int, T*> pair) const
    {
        return (pair.second == t_);
    }

private:
    T* t_;
};
```

and Here's the functor that's called "erase product" where I have to use my 'is equal' product:

```
class EraseProduct
public:
    EraseProduct(multimap <int, Produit*>& multimap) : multimap_(multimap) {} ; // constructor that initializes 'multimap_' attribute

    multimap <int, Product*>& operator()(Product* product)
    {
         auto it = find_if(multimap_.begin(), multimap_.end(), USE_EQUAL_FUNCTOR_HERE)

         if (it != multimap_.end)
         multimap_.erase(it)

         return multimap_;

    }
private:
    multimap<int, Product*>& multimap_;
```

*Product* is a class. So my question is about where I wrote "USE_EQUAL_FUNCTOR_HERE". I can't figure out the correct syntax. I tried:

```
IsEqual(), IsEqual(product)
```

and some other stuff.

THanks in advance!

Comment: `IsEqual(product)` didn't work?  What was the error?

Comment: Where are you getting the `T` from in `pair<int, T*>`?

Comment: You probably forgot `template <class T> class isEqual{....`

Comment: Voting to close, since comments are guessing the missing code and guessing the missing error message.

Comment: The [code compiling](https://godbolt.org/g/ch5fG5), you should read a good book about C++.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to make `isEqual` a class template. As posted, it is not.
2. Then, you would use `Product` as the template parameter to create an instance and use it as an argument to `find_if`.

---

```
template <typename T>
class isEqual
{
   ...
};
```

and

```
auto it = find_if(multimap_.begin(), multimap_.end(), isEqual<Product>());
```